# Python: Factory Boy to generate List of length specified on object creation

Tags: python, unit-testing, factory-boy

I'm trying to use Factoryboy to create a list in an object of the length specified when created.

I can create the list, but every attempt to create a list with the length specified causes issues due to the lazy nature of the provided length/size.

This is what I have so far:

```
class FooFactory(factory.Factory):

    class Meta:
        model = command.Foo

    foo_uuid = factory.Faker("uuid4")
    bars = factory.List([
        factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: BarFactory()
        for _ in range(3))
    ])
```

This will create a list of 3 random Bars. I have tried using a combination of Params and exclude, but because range expects an Int, and the int won't be lazily loaded until later, it causes an error.

I would like something similar to how one to many relationships are generated with post_generation ie.

```
foo = FooFactory(number_of_bars=5)
```

Anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Main solution

Two things are needed for this:
[parameters](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#parameters)
and [`LazyAttribute`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#lazyattribute)
(the links point to their documentation, for more detail).

Parameters are like factory attributes that are not passed to the instance that will be created.
In this case, they provide a way to parametrize the length of the list of `Bar`s.

But in order to use parameters to customize a field in the factory, we need to have access to `self`,
that is, the instance being built.
We can achieve that with `LazyAttribute`, which is a declaration that takes a function with one argument:
the object being built.
Just what we needed.

So the snippet in the question could be re-written as follows:

```py
class FooFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = command.Foo

    class Params:
        number_of_bars = 1

    foo_uuid = factory.Faker("uuid4")
    bars = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda self: [BarFactory()] * self.number_of_bars)
```

And used like this:

```py
foo = FooFactory(number_of_bars=3)
```

If the `number_of_bars` argument is not provided, the default of `1` is used.

### Drawbacks

Sadly, there is a some limitation to what we can do here.

The preferred way to use a factory in the definition of another factory is via
[`SubFactory`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#subfactory).
That is preferred for two reasons:

1. it respects the build strategy used for the parent factory
2. it collects extra keyword arguments to customize the subfactory

The first one means that if we used `SubFactory` to build a `Bar` in `FooFactory`
and called `FooFactory` with `FooFactory.create` or `FooFactory.build`,
the `Bar` subfactory would respect that and use the same strategy.
In summary, the build strategy only builds an instance,
while the create strategy builds **and** saves the instance to the persistent storage being used,
for example a database, so respecting this choice is important.
See the [docs](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#strategies)
for more details.

The second one means that we can directly customize attributes of `Bar` when calling `FooFactory`.
For example:

```py
foo = FooFactory(bar__id=2)
```

would set the `id` of the `bar` of `foo` to be `2` instead of what the `Bar` subfactory would generate by default.

But I could not find a way to use `SubFactory` **and** a dynamic length via `Params`.
There is no way, as far as I know, to access the value of a parameter in a context where FactoryBoy expects a `SubFactory`.
The problem is that the declarations that give us access to the object being built always expect a final *value* to be returned,
not another factory to be called later.
This means that, in the example above, if we write instead:

```py
class FooFactory(factory.Factory):
    # ... rest of the factory
    bars = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda self: [factory.SubFactory(BarFactory)] * self.number_of_bars)
```

then calling it like

```py
foo = FooFactory(number_of_bars=3)
```

would result in a `foo` that has a list of 3 `BarFactory` in `foo.bars` instead of a list of 3 `Bar`s.
And using [`SelfAttribute`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#selfattribute),
which is a way to reference another attribute of the instance being built, doesn't work either
because it is not evaluated before the rest of the expression in a declaration like this:

```py
class FooFactory(factory.Factory):
    # ... rest of the factory
    bars = factory.List([factory.SubFactory(BarFactory)] * SelfAttribute("number_of_bars"))
```

That raises `TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'SelfAttribute'`.
A possible workaround is to call `BarFactory` beforehand and pass it to `FooFactory`:

```py
number_of_bars = 3
bars = BarFactory.create_batch(number_of_bars)
foo = FooFactory(bars=bars)
```

But that's certainly not as nice.

Another one that I found out recently is [`RelatedFactoryList`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#relatedfactorylist).
But that's still experimental and it doesn't seem to have a way to access parameters.
Additionally, since it's generated **after** the base factory, it also might not work if the instance constructor
expects that attribute as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, @Yunnosch. My original answer was vague (and a little off too). I edited it to try and make it better.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Seems this is an [open issue](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/767) and people are working on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to pass the length of a list and retain the ability to set additional properties on the subfactory.  It requires creating a post_generation method.

```
class FooFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = command.Foo

    foo_uuid = factory.Faker("uuid4")
    bars__count = 5  # Optional: default number of bars to create

@factory.post_generation
def bars(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
    if not create:
        return

    num_bars = kwargs.get('count', 0)
    color = kwargs.get('color')

    if num_bars > 0:
        self.bars = [BarFactory(color=color)] * num_bars
    elif extracted:
        self.bars=extracted
```

any parameter with the construct `modelname__paramname` will be passed to the `post_generation` method as `paramname` in kwargs.

You can then call the FooFactory  as:

```
FooFactory.create(bars__color='blue')
```

and it will create Foo with 5 Bars (the default value).

You can also call FooFactory and tell it to create 10 Bars.

```
FooFactory.create(bars__color='blue', bars__count=10)
```

Comment: Just a note, `bars__count` is a required attribute on `FooFactory` or an error is thrown as `count` is not an attribute of `Bar`