# factory-boy: Passing "size" on the fly to RelatedFactoryList

Tags: python, factory-boy

Given the following factories, one using `RelatedFactoryList` to create 2 Prices related to the Product:

```
class PriceFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker("sentence", nb_words=2)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Price

class Product(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.Faker("sentence", nb_words=2)
    prices = factory.RelatedFactoryList(
        PriceFactory,
        factory_related_name="product",
        size=2,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
```

I know that I can pass information to the related factory doing something like this:

```
 product = ProductFactory.create(prices__name="All have this name")
```

Is there a way I can also change the `size`, or count, of prices created using an argument to `ProductFactory.create`?  This does not work:

```
 product = ProductFactory.create(prices__size=5)
```

Comment: Have you found some solution for this? I have been looking for this as well. So far the best solution I have seen is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802176/python-factory-boy-to-generate-list-of-length-specified-on-object-creation.

Comment: Also, https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/767 seems to give a proper workaround for this.